# wicket ExportToolbar not refreshing on table update

Tags: wicket

I'm having some trouble with ExportToolbar updating when table content is updated. The first time I click the CSV export link it works fine, but then if the table is updated and I click the CSV link again I get an export of the same previous table content. I'll try and show the setup, and how the data is changing. I hope someone has seen this behavior before and can point me to the right place. I've been using wicket for 9 years, and never been so stuck as I am in this. Thanks in advance for any help.

Wicket version 7.7.0, oops no 7.4.0 (Edit 1), sorry

Here is the definition of the table:

```
    //main report table init:
    List<ReportRow> records = db.getVisitCountsByGrouping( getSelectedMonth());
    mainProvider = new SearchProvider<>( records, "id" );
    mainProvider.setSummationRow(sumRow);
    this.mainColumns = new ArrayList<>();
    //...columns added....
    mainTable = new DefaultDataTable<ReportRow,String>("mainTable", mainColumns, mainProvider, 25);
    mainTable.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    rft = new ReportFooterToolbar(mainTable, sumRow, this);
    rft.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    mainTable.addBottomToolbar(rft);
    exportToolbar = new ExportToolbar(mainTable, new PropertyModel<String>(this,"mainTableExportFileName"));
    exportToolbar.addDataExporter(new CSVDataExporter());
    mainTable.addBottomToolbar(exportToolbar);
    add(mainTable);
```

here is the update Ajax caller:

```
    Form form = new Form("form");
    ArrayList<String> months = new ArrayList<>();
    months.add("January");
    months.add("February");
    months.add("March");
    months.add("April");
    months.add("May");
    months.add("June");
    months.add("July");
    months.add("August");
    months.add("September");
    months.add("October");
    months.add("November");
    months.add("December");
    DropDownChoice<String> selectMonth = new DropDownChoice<String>("selectMonth", new PropertyModel<String>(this, "selectedMonth"), months);
    selectMonth.add(new AjaxFormComponentUpdatingBehavior("change") {
        @Override
        protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
           updateMainTable(target);
        }
    });
    form.add(selectMonth);
    add(form);
```

the method updateMainTable(target):

`public void updateMainTable( AjaxRequestTarget target ) {
        List<ReportRow> records = db.getVisitCountsByGrouping( getSelectedMonth());
        mainProvider.update(records);
        target.add(rft);
        target.add(mainTable);

    }`

So the table is updating just fine, my provider has an update method that works like a champ, but I can't seem to figure out why the export toolbar is not updating after the first export, and I'm worried the property model isn't updating for the filename either. It is strange, and doesn't seem to be following the usual wicket model update behavior.

Has anyone had a problem like this with the export tool bar, or am I doing something wrong, or not doing the something correctly? Thanks for any help.

(Edit 1): Also added the source for the search provider:

```
public class SearchProvider<T> extends SortableDataProvider {
private List<T> list = null;
private ReportRow sumRow = null;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public SearchProvider( List<T> listOfStuffs, String sortColumn ) { 
    this(listOfStuffs, sortColumn, true);
}

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public SearchProvider( List<T> listOfStuffs, String sortColumn, boolean ascendingFlag ) { 
    if( listOfStuffs == null ) 
        listOfStuffs = new ArrayList<>();
    this.list = listOfStuffs;
    setSort(sortColumn, (ascendingFlag?SortOrder.ASCENDING:SortOrder.DESCENDING) );
}

public void update( List<T> listOfStuffs ) {
    if( listOfStuffs == null ) 
        listOfStuffs = new ArrayList<>();
    this.list = listOfStuffs;
            if( sumRow != null ) {
                //update sums
                sumRow.resetSums();
                for( T t : list ){
                    sumRow.add((ReportRow)t);
                }
            }

}

private SortableDataProviderComparator comparator = new SortableDataProviderComparator();

public void setSummationRow(ReportRow sumRow) {
    this.sumRow = sumRow;
    sumRow.resetSums();
    for( T t : this.list ){
        sumRow.add((ReportRow)t);
    }
}
class SortableDataProviderComparator implements Comparator<T>, Serializable {
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public int compare( final T b1, final T b2 ) {
        PropertyModel<Comparable> c1 = new PropertyModel<Comparable>(b1, getSort().getProperty().toString());
        PropertyModel<Comparable> c2 = new PropertyModel<Comparable>(b2, getSort().getProperty().toString());

        if( c1.getObject() == null && c2.getObject() == null ) return 0;
        if( c1.getObject() == null ) return 1;
        if( c2.getObject() == null ) return -1;
        int result = c1.getObject().compareTo( c2.getObject() );
        if( !getSort().isAscending() ) result *= -1;
        return result;
    }
}

public Iterator<T> iterator( final long first, final long count ) {
    Collections.sort( this.list, comparator );
    return this.list.subList( (int)first, (int)(first+count) ).iterator();
}

public IModel<T> model( final Object o ) {
    return new AbstractReadOnlyModel<T>() {
        @Override
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        public T getObject() { return (T) o; }
    };
}

public long size() { return list.size(); }
```

}

(Edit 2) Another update: I added some logging in the ExportToolbar.onConfigure() method to make sure my provider is working and all seems well, could the problem be in the CSVDataExporter itself?

Here is my debug logging and output:

```
exportToolbar = new ExportToolbar(mainTable, new PropertyModel<String>(this,"mainTableExportFileName")) {
        @Override
        protected void onConfigure() {
            super.onConfigure();
            //setFileNameModel( new Model<String>( getMainTableExportFileName() ));
            if( getFileNameModel() != null )
                logger.debug("ExportToolbar file name model: "+ getFileNameModel().toString() +" file name: "+ getFileNameModel().getObject() );

            Iterator it = getTable().getDataProvider().iterator(0, getTable().getDataProvider().size());
            while( it.hasNext() ) {
                ReportRow r = (ReportRow) it.next();
                logger.debug("ExportToolbar data: "+ r.getCategory() +" "+ r.get1() +" "+ r.get2() + " "+ r.get3() );
            }
        }
    };
```

log file:

```
2017-03-06 12:28:52 DEBUG ReportPanel:244 - ExportToolbar file name model: Model:classname=[org.apache.wicket.model.PropertyModel]:nestedModel=[[ReportPanel [Component id = panel]]]:expression=[mainTableExportFileName] file name: 2017-January-AllVisits-ByReason
    2017-03-06 12:28:52 DEBUG ReportPanel:249 - ExportToolbar data: add/drop 0 38 63
    2017-03-06 12:28:52 DEBUG ReportPanel:249 - ExportToolbar data: withdraw 0 0 0
    2017-03-06 12:28:52 DEBUG ReportPanel:249 - ExportToolbar data: audit 0 0 3
    2017-03-06 12:28:52 DEBUG ReportPanel:249 - ExportToolbar data: advising 0 27 35
    2017-03-06 12:28:52 DEBUG ReportPanel:249 - ExportToolbar data: prospective 0 2 0
    2017-03-06 12:28:52 DEBUG ReportPanel:249 - ExportToolbar data: other 0 19 38
    2017-03-06 12:29:26 DEBUG ReportPanel:244 - ExportToolbar file name model: Model:classname=[org.apache.wicket.model.PropertyModel]:nestedModel=[[ReportPanel [Component id = panel]]]:expression=[mainTableExportFileName] file name: 2017-February-AllVisits-ByReason
    2017-03-06 12:29:26 DEBUG ReportPanel:249 - ExportToolbar data: add/drop 3 5 1
    2017-03-06 12:29:26 DEBUG ReportPanel:249 - ExportToolbar data: withdraw 0 1 0
    2017-03-06 12:29:26 DEBUG ReportPanel:249 - ExportToolbar data: audit 0 3 4
    2017-03-06 12:29:26 DEBUG ReportPanel:249 - ExportToolbar data: advising 8 6 6
    2017-03-06 12:29:26 DEBUG ReportPanel:249 - ExportToolbar data: prospective 3 1 2
    2017-03-06 12:29:26 DEBUG ReportPanel:249 - ExportToolbar data: other 8 8 7
```

(Edit 3) I was able to get the filename property model to update correctly and consistently get the table export link to work, I still have an issue, but I was able to get this export link to be consistent by creating the table again on update and addOrReplace(mainTable) instead of updating it. That's how I was able to get the createExportLink() method to run again, otherwise it was only happening on creation of the ExportToolbar and never again. So now, let's say the ExportToolbar looks like this:

```
exportToolbar = new ExportToolbar(mainTable, new PropertyModel<String>(this,"mainTableExportFileName") ) {
        @Override
        protected Component createExportLink(String componentId, final IDataExporter dataExporter ) {
            logger.debug("createExportLink: "+ componentId +" exporter: "+ dataExporter.toString());
            Component component = super.createExportLink(componentId, dataExporter);
            return component;
        }
    };      
    exportToolbar.addDataExporter(new CSVDataExporter() );
```

Now the trick seems to be that everything will work if I delete history in the browser and click the link, but otherwise changing the table dynamically and selecting the link gives me the data from the last time I clicked the link. So it seems the link is cached. I am infiltrating the component creation, how can I alter the component to ensure the csv data isn't cached?

Comment: I think the bug must be in SearchProvider class. CSVDataExporter uses the dataProvider in its `#exportData()` method. Are you sure you use 7.7.0? It is not yet released.

Comment: Could you post your SearchProvider class source code (mainly method iterator() and update(records). You seem to have a bug there somewhere. The filename might not update, because I can't see where you update it. You use a property model, so I'd expect, that you have an attribute `mainTableExportFileName` on your page. I'd further expect, you change this in your `updateMainTable` method, but you don't.

Comment: not sure why I typed 7.7.0, I'm using 7.4.0, and I should have just condensed the search provider for readability. Thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer, with some playing. The trick was to override the create Export Link and make the ResourceStreamResource then set cache timeout on it. Wicket hurts sometimes....

```
        exportToolbar = new ExportToolbar(mainTable, new PropertyModel<String>(this,"mainTableExportFileName"), new AbstractReadOnlyModel<String>() {
        @Override
        public String getObject() { return getMainTableExportFileName(); } 
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Component createExportLink(String componentId, final IDataExporter dataExporter ) {
            ResourceStreamResource resource = new ResourceStreamResource() {
                @Override
                protected IResourceStream getResourceStream() {
                    return new DataExportResourceStreamWriter(dataExporter, getTable());
                }
            };
            resource.setFileName(getFileNameModel().getObject() + "." + dataExporter.getFileNameExtension());
            resource.setCacheDuration(Duration.ONE_SECOND);
            return new ResourceLink<Void>(componentId, resource).setBody(dataExporter.getDataFormatNameModel());
        }
    };
```